# SVG. Задать отступ сверху

Tags: css, svg

Как задать отступ сверху (аналог CSS - `margin-top`), чтобы изображение смещалось от верха к центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 290 290" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background:new 0 0 290 290;">
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <rect y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <script xmlns="" type="text/javascript" id="useragent-switcher">navigator.__defineGetter__("userAgent", function() {return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.9 Safari/537.36"})</script></svg>
```

Comment: `transform="translate(25, 0)"` так можно

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev  почему не минусуешь - тут же явно видно что в люстре делали ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аналогом `margin-top`   в `svg` является изменение атрибута `y-min` `viewBox="x-min y-min 290 290"`.
Увеличивая   `y-min` в положительном значении мы может поднимать изображение, уменьшая опускать изображение. 
В вашем примере svg изображение занимает всё полотно, поэтому нельзя сразу сдвигать изображение сверху-вниз, так как изображение обрежется снизу.

Ниже пример вашего кода из которого я убрал ненужные строчки, которые оставляет `Adobe Illustrator`и обернул svg код в `div`, чтобы изменяя его ширину и высоту в процентах менять размер всей svg картинки. Это сделано, чтобы изображение было адаптивно. Красная рамка добавлена, чтобы показать границу svg изображения. 
Сейчас картинка занимает полностью всё svg полотно.

```css
container {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">   
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 290 290" style="border:1px solid red;" >
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <rect y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
    </g>
     </svg> 
  </div>
```

- Теперь увеличиваем масштаб `viewBox` в два раза для уменьшения в два
  раза изображения `svg`  было - `viewBox="0 0 290 290"` стало -
  `viewBox="0 0 580` `580`"

```css
.container {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">   
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 0 580 580" style="border:1px solid red;" >
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <rect y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
    </g>
     </svg> 
  </div>
```

- Теперь сдвигаем весь блок фигур вниз, для этого изменяем параметр
  `y-min=(-145)`         у  `viewBox="0 -145 580 580"`

```css
.container {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">   
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 -145 580 580" style="border:1px solid red;" >
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <rect y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
    </g>
     </svg> 
  </div>
```

- Можно изменять размеры svg изображения, изменяя проценты контейнера, оставляя изображение адаптивным.

```css
.container {
   width:10%;
   height:10%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">   
   <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  viewBox="0 -145 580 580" >
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <rect y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" y="110" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
 <rect x="220" width="70" height="70" fill="#00aeef"/>
    </g>
     </svg> 
  </div>
```

Comment: как всегда безупречен !